# Show current temperature in React NavBar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out a way to show my city current temperature in React's [Navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) through [React Open Weather](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-open-weather) but I'm a beginner in web development and don't know how to implement it, I don't know if this is possible in the first place so I asked first, this is what I've developed so far in my navbar code.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Navbar,Nav,NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavBar.css';

export default function NavBar (){

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return(
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
         <Navbar.Brand as={NavLink} to= '/' className={"px-3"}>
           <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>Home</h4>
         </Navbar.Brand>
         <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
         <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <NavDropdown title= "Tools" className={"px-3 h3"} id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/ToDoList'> 
                   <h3 className={"fontSize3"}>To-Do List</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Calculator'>
                  < h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Calculator</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Countdown'>
                  < h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Countdown</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Stopwatch'>
                  < h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Stopwatch</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Notepad'>
                  <h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Notepad</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item>
                  <h3 className={"fontSize3"} onClick={handleShow}>Clock</h3>
                    <Modal show={show} centered size="lg" onHide={handleClose}>
                      <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Time</Modal.Title>
                      </Modal.Header>
                    <h1>It is currently {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h1>
                  </Modal>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Calendar'>
                  <h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Calendar</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                <NavDropdown.Item as={NavLink} to= '/Scheduled'>
                  <h3 className={"fontSize3"}>Scheduled</h3>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
               </NavDropdown>   
              </Nav>
      
              <Nav>
               <Nav.Link  as={NavLink} to= '/Login' className={"px-3"}>
                 <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>Login / Sign Up</h4>
               </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to= '/AboutUs' className={"px-3"} >
                 <h4 className={"fontSize4"}>About us</h4>
              </Nav.Link>
              </Nav>
           </Navbar.Collapse>
         </Navbar>


    );
  
}
```

And this is how it looks
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try running it? Got any error /something ?

Comment: pick a spot you want it to appear and put the HTML containing the weather at that spot. You'll likely need to add some CSS to position it.

Comment: @Furquan It runs fine, it just dosent have any weather implementation yet

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm new to web development, could you give me more pointers on how that's done? But thank you for the answer

Comment: I misled you a bit. Use `Navbar.text` - the link here is from the very documentation link you sent in your question. Please slow down and READ the docs - the answer was right in front of you. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-text-link

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you again, I've tried to simple approach of this,
              <Navbar.Text>
              <ReactWeather
                forecast="today"
                apikey="my actual api key"
                type="city"
                city="Munich"
              />
              </Navbar.Text>

but the console gives me this error TypeError: dayDataFiltered[0] is undefined and the component says Loading..., am I suppoused to render this first somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
const [weather, setWeather] = useState(null);
const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.054810&lon=19.927839&appid={API_KEY}&units=metrics';
let temperature;

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        setWeather(response.data);
        temperature = response.data.main.temp;
    });
}, []);
```

And then I put `{Math.floor((temperature)-273.15)}&deg;C` in a div inside my Navbar. It works, although it's definitely not the cleanest way. :-)